# Помогите переписать код с C++ на C#

Tags: c#, c++

Шарпы ругаются на на эту строку

```
{cin>>buf; if(buf=='1') a[i][j]=1; else a[i][j]=0;}.
```

я перерисовал как

```
buf = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

и так далее. выдает ошибку что нельзя ввести больше одного символа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int a[1000][1000],n;
bool prov(int x,int y,int k)
{
for(int i=x;i<=x+k;i++)
for(int j=y;j<=y+k;j++)
if(a[i][j]==0) return false;
return true;    
}

int main()
{
char buf;
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{cin>>buf; if(buf=='1') a[i][j]=1; else a[i][j]=0;}

for(int k=n-1;k>=0;k--)
for(int i=0;i<n-k;i++)
for(int j=0;j<n-k;j++)
if(prov(i,j,k)) {cout<<(k+1)*(k+1);return 0;}

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Сами переписывайте, а как возникнут конкретные проблемы - обращайтесь сюда.

Comment: В чём у вас сложности? В коде нет ничего сверхъестественного, чтобы его не переписать самому

Comment: Шарпы ругаются на на эту строку {cin>>buf; if(buf=='1') a[i][j]=1; else a[i][j]=0;}. я перерисовал как buf = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); и так далее. выдает ошибку что нельзя ввести больше одного символа

Comment: `char` - это один символ. Метод `Console.ReadLine` возвращает строку (`string`) - массив символов.

Answer (score 1):

Определите buf как **string**. А далее `buf = Console.ReadLine();`
Сравнивайте тоже по строке, в C# это двойная кавычка: `if (buf == "1") a[i,j] = 1;`
В любом случае, код будет примерно таким:

```cs
class Program
    {
        static int[,] a = new int[1000,1000];

        static bool Prov(int x, int y, int k)
        {
            for (int i = x; i <= x + k; i++)
                for (int j = y; j <= y + k; j++)
                    if (a[i,j] == 0) return false;
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string buf;
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    buf = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (buf == "1") a[i,j] = 1;
                    else a[i,j] = 0;
                }

            for (int k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--)
                for (int i = 0; i < n - k; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < n - k; j++)
                        if (Prov(i, j, k))
                            Console.WriteLine((k + 1) * (k + 1));
        }
    }
```